# Biquad high-pass filter not working as expected

Tags: audio, highpass-filter, c++, biquad

I'm trying to implement a high-pass filter using the the coefficients described in RBJ's well-known EQ cookbook (see https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).
However, when I run white noise through the filter, the output doesn't sound high-passed at all, at times it even sounds slightly low-passed.

Here is an audio example with the cut-off frequency being modulated between 20 Hz and 18 kHz and the Q factor being set at 0.707: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGE41VAnn0s

The filter is implemented in C++ as follows:

```
float process( float const in )
{
    float const omega = PI2 * frequency / 44100.0f;
    float const alpha = std::sin( omega ) / 2.0f * q;

    b2 = b0 = (1 + std::cos( omega )) / 2.0f;
    b1 = -(1 + std::cos( omega ));
    a0 = 1.0f + alpha;
    a1 = -2.0f * std::cos( omega );
    a2 = 1.0f - alpha;

    b0 /= a0; b1 /= a0; b2 /= a0; a1 /= a0; a2 /= a0;

    float const out = 
        b0 * in +
        b1 * x1 +
        b2 * x2 -
        a1 * y1 -
        a2 * y2;

    x2 = x1;
    x1 = in;
    y2 = y1;
    y1 = out;

    return out;
}
```

Oddly enough, I have also tried to use the low-pass coefficients and that seems to work as expected.

Now what's the reason for the high-pass filter above not sounding like it should? Have I made a mistake that I can't find?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a working implementation of cookbook filters - https://sourceforge.net/p/equalizerapo/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ ... take a look.

Comment: Does it work if the frequency isn’t modulated?

Answer (score 2):

There is (at least) one error in your routine. It concerns the definition of `alpha`. The correct formula is

$$\alpha=\frac{\sin(\omega_0)}{2Q}$$

However, you implemented

$$\alpha=\frac{\sin(\omega_0)\cdot Q}{2}$$

But that shouldn't influence the function of the filter as a high pass filter; it just implements the inverse of the given $Q$ value.

Other than that, it's of course important that the variables `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` retain their value between function calls. I'm not sure if and where you take care of that.

As a final remark, you might want to think about if it's really necessary to recompute the filter coefficients each time a new sample arrives.